# Using Python, how can I check which object in an `if or` statement returned `True`?

Tags: python, list, select, if-statement

```
if mo.exists() or ao.exists():
        for d in [mo,ao]
```

I don't want to run through both objects in the list, only the one that returns True.
Cant seem to figure it out?

Thanks

Comment: What if both are `True`?

Comment: 'thefourtheye' answered both of us. Thank you pal, I learned something today :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a generator expression like this and filter the objects which return `True` for the `exists()` call,

```
for item in (obj for obj in (mo, ao) if obj.exists()):
    ...
```

Comment: Another idea: `for item in filter(lambda x: x.exists(), (mo, ao))`.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Thats true, but Python community likes to move away from both `filter` and `lambda` functions, [as BDFL wants to do so](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196)

Answer (score 1):

```
res=[d for d in [mo,ao] if d.exists()]
for r in res:
```

capture all True in res list and iterate over res.

Answer (score 0):

Just separate the `if` statement:

```
if mo.exists():
    for d in mo:
        #do stuff
elif ao.exists():
    for d in ao:
        #do other stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

```
if mo.exists() or ao.exists():
    if not mo:
       for d in ao:
          #do 
    else:
       for d in mo:
          #do
```

Comment: Should be `if not mo.exists():` What if both exist? What if exists() is fairly expensive to evaluate (like looking up in a database)? Better to use one of the other solutions that only call exists() once per object.